# Google compute, Wordpress(click to deploy) - "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I got [Error establishing a database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3z23.png) showing on my website two days ago. But I didn't change anything when it happened. The website was build at click to deploy wordpress in compute engine.

And I haven't changed anything from SSH or any other parts to fixed the issue, it returns normal two days later.

I want to know which part is wrong to cause the message and how can I fix it to avoid future errors?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much control you have over your database and web site, so start with the basics. Verify that your database is up and that your ODBC/JDBC connections are open. And check the logs for any errors. Go into your WordPress configuration settings and see if it is connected to the database. Fix any connection problems you find. Also verify the username and password used for your database login, to confirm it is correct and not changed.  You can also try the old-fashioned restart your database and your website and see if the error is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But before I changed anything from there, the website returns normal. How can that happened? am I still using your method to run it again?